# Какие браузеры стоит поддерживать на своем сайте и почему ?

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, css, javascript

Какие браузеры стоит поддерживать на своем сайте и почему ?

Comment: Я бы начал с вопроса, а почему вообще такой вопрос стоит? Что настолько сложный дизайн сайта, что нужно много переписывать в стилях? Или может очень сложный Javascript?

Comment: Даже html5 тэги не все браузеры поддерживают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делай поддержку всех браузеров (FF,Opera,IE,Google Chrom). Это во-первых кроссобраузерно, а значит качественно. Во-вторых, если делать сайт кроссобраузерно - это учит более строгому синтаксису.
Например, если у меня раньше были с этим постоянно проблемы, то сейчас только иногда появляются проблемы в IE. Главное большой опыт от этого получаешь.
Т.ч. делай под все браузеры, будешь умнее :) + Работодатель будет это ценить. Ну всё же можно принебречь старыми версиями IE,Opera. Т.к. их почти никто не использует. 
CSS 3 можете использовать, сейчас уже все браузеры автообновляются, т.ч. поддержка будет я так думаю у 70% пользователей точно, даже наверняка больше.

Comment: Невяжется както вот это в вашем посте: 

    Делай поддержку всех браузеров (FF,Opera,IE,Google Chrom). 
причем даже само с собой предложение не вяжется, браузеров в разы(во много раз больше чем перечисленно в скобках, хотябы тот же нетскейп и сафари, где же они? или пользователи мака для нас не пользователи?)

Далее не вяжется первая часть предложения(где вы про поддержку всех браузеров) и использование CSS3 хотябы потому что тот же IE6-IE7 никогда не обновятся для его поддержки. а на данный момент браузеры весьма популярные)

Comment: > если делать сайт кроссобраузерно - это учит более строгому синтаксису

Это учит работе с "костылями", а не строгому синтаксису ))

Answer (score 7):

Все просто.

```
1) зайти на сайт http://alexvaleev.ru/browserstat/ или подобный.
2) Определить потенциальных клиентов.
3) Решить скольких(какой %) вы готовы потерять.
4) Исходя из процента вероятных потерь выбрать кол-во браузеров с наибольшим кол-вом клиентов
5) Вести поддержку под выбраные браузеры.
```

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю: в корпоративном секторе очень жесткие ограничения, отличные от всего мира. В прошлом году были заказчики, которые категорически требовали работоспособности под IE6

Answer (score 2):

Если сайт не оптимизирован под мобильные устройства, то как минимум:

1. IE9+
2. Firefox (последний)
3. Chrome (последний)
4. Safari (под MacOS)

Процент пользователей остальных браузеров настолько мал, что не имеет особого смысла их поддерживать.

Answer (score 0):

осла ie только нужно поддерживать

если в осле работает, значит везде будет работать

Comment: Это еще не факт. Если верстать сначала под Firefox, то потом бывают различия в отображении под хромом и наоборот. Тоже самое по поводу js. То что канает в firefox, не всегда проканывает в хроме.

Comment: тоже не соглашусь ) у нас на IE6 все правильно работает, под Оперой работает криво.